# Can't find OPENSSL_cpuid_setup() to load custom engine for OpenSSL in C/C++

Tags: c++, random, import, openssl

I'm trying to force OpenSSL's random number generator to use RDRAND, as described in the OpenSSL wiki [here](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Random_Numbers#Hardware) and also cited in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30145969/4028758) Stackoverflow post.

However, when I try to call this function `OPENSSL_cpuid_setup();`, I get the following error:

> error: ‘OPENSSL_cpuid_setup’ was not declared in this scope

I've imported the following files, neither of which contain the function:

```
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/engine.h>
```

I've done some digging and it appears the function is present in `cryptlib.h` of OpenSSL, but I can't import that file.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69986668/4028758) Stackoverflow answer seems to suggest that I don't need to call that function; indeed, when I comment that function out, the remainder of the code runs without error.
Does anyone know what file I'm supposed to import, and whether the function call is necessary?